# Configure script failing

Tags: linux, configuration, prolog, configuration-files, yap

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 in a VMBox and now trying to install "YAP Prolog". Therefore I download the code using "git clone ..."  and obtain the code, which i have to configure and build.
Configuring and building works fine on my OSX, but somehow on my linux distribution i get an error during configuration. I dont understand it and could not find anything useful in the internet. Is
 it possible that I need some packages? If yes, how to find out which?

I put the config.log to google docs: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NqWwNXbHHnUT0x9uoxVqobTtmJQIrUW_4DnFrXFGn28/edit

Thank you!

Comment: From the `config.log` file it looks like you might be missing `libreadline-dev`.

Comment: already installed, but did not solve the problem =/

Comment: Are you sure you have the `dev` package and not just plain `libreadline`?

Comment: i tried both, and just "sudo apt-get install libreadline" gives me a "unable to locate package"... but "apt-get install libreadline-dev" gives me a "already at the newest version"

Comment: If you're using `Ubuntu` I believe the readline package is called `readline-common`

Comment: thanks for the time you already spent! readline-common is also installed, but does not solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The missing library was libncurses5-dev!